# Appreciation email after interview

Tags: faculty-application, interview

I had a virtual interview with  a hiring committee in a university for a faculty position.  Do I need to send an email of appreciation after that? If so, to whom I should send? Can I send one email to all interviewer in one email? or it must be separate emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you met with them as a committee, then I would send a quick email to the committee chair. It can be very minimal, thanking them for their time and expressing your continued interest in the position.

Probably not totally necessary, but can signal interest, which is occasionally useful if you are perceived as a candidate who may have lots of competing interviews and offers. It reiterates you are serious about their particular opportunity.